# UnsupportedClassVersionError on Websphare 8.5 on REDHAT 2.6

Tags: java, linux, jsf, websphere

i have a problem when deploy my JSF 2.1 application on WebSphere 8.5 on RedHat 2.6. i got the following exception:

nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 bad major version; class=com/mycom/encdec/myclass,

it clear from this exception that the  JVM on the client side is older than one used at compile time. But actually it is same. and the follwong is some of extra info:

1. code compiled on JDK 1.6, javap command gives  minor version: 0 and major version: 50.
2. the same ear file works fine on other platform likes wondows.
3. spring 3.1 is used

here is some of properties from  System.getProperties() on target machine :

1. java.fullversion=JRE 1.6.0 IBM J9 2.6 Linux amd64-64 C...
2. com.ibm.oti.vm.library.version=26
3. java.vm.name=IBM J9 VM
4. os.version=2.6.32-431.23.3.el6.x86_64
5. java.vm.vendor=IBM Corporation
6. java.class.version=50.0
7. java.compiler=j9jit26

Could someone please tell me how to overcome this issue? Thanks all

Comment: Recheck the version of com/mycom/encdec/myclass  Also, websphere may pick up another JVM than you think.

Comment: Maybe not your class, but some library it is using, is compiled with Java 7. Are you sure about other environments? Since in WebSphere v8.5 you can switch to Java 7, so maybe you did that on other environments and thats why it is working there.